# Change value of translateX and size of element based on size of parent element OR size of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope that this question is not too specific so it can relate to others problems...

I have two elements, a child and a parent, with the child element rotating around the parent using CSS animations.

```
<div class="planet">

<div class="moon"></div>

</div>
```

The moons animation is set so the moon will load ontop of the planet in the same position, but is pushed out with translateX then roatated, like so:

```
@keyframes myOrbit {
from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(200px) rotate(0deg); }
to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(200px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Think of it as a planet with a moon rotating around the planet.

When the user resizes the window the planets height/width will resize, but I also need the moons height/width to resize AND the distance between it and the planet needs to lower.

I have set up an example here... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVvYbR

Would this be possible to acheive with just CSS, or would javascript be needed? I will use jQuery if need be, (I am not great at it though) but I would think a pure CSS solution would be cleaner... maybe I'm wrong on that one.

I should also note that the way it is set up currently (with the planet div holding the moon, is so that I can have multiple children (multiple moons). However I also think that this would mean having a massive amount of different animations for moons/planets which need different translateX's... So maybe jQuery is a better solution there...

If I am not clear on anything please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: JS would be your solution. Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104099/2599266) for why and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14091251/2599266) for some ideas on how to do it. Hope these help!

Comment: Just use percent everywhere? https://codepen.io/wilmaknattern/pen/VegOPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do it with just css. You can use viewport units so all values will depend on viewport size.

```
.planet {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
      background: url(http://placehold.it/940x940) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: 1;
}

.moon {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/140x140) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit 20s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: myOrbit 20s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: myOrbit 20s linear infinite;
            animation: myOrbit 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myOrbit {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(20vw) rotate(0deg); z-index:1}
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(20vw) rotate(-360deg); z-index:2}
}
```

Sample -> [here](https://codepen.io/frontendguy/pen/zreQpG)

Probably you will need to add some media queries to handle different screen aspect ratios. Current viewport units support -> [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Ah thank you that's great works really well. One question: why have you added z-index to from and to?
Also is there a way to get translateX out of the @keyframes and in the general style rule? So I can control it with jquery

Comment: z-index is to force browser to calculate dimensions on resize (it forces calc and paint). Yes you can move translateX outside animation.

Comment: It seems to break the animation if I take translateX out. If i put it in .moon {     transform: translateX(20vw); } it doesn't seem to like it. i must be doing something wrong here